# Replace parentheses in URL strings

Tags: javascript, regex, urlencode

I have string with URL links like below. But urls are breaking when urls have parenthesis like below. The urls are breaking at the start of parenthesis in URL.

```
This is test http://ang.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Tutorial_(Wikipedia_links)
```

Can we replace parentheses with other ASCII characters using javascript regex?

Comment: you can use url encode ?

Comment: Take a look at this previous SO Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript If you are having an issue with encoding, which I am assuming you do, this could get the job done in a more robust manner.

Answer (score 27):

Use the `string.replace()` method.

```
url = url.replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29');
```